# Error en Ionic: "Error: No platforms added to this project"

Tags: ionic

Al ejecutar el comando `ionic build andorid` me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`.
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Has buscado a que se puede deber el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de hacer `ionic build android` debes agregar la plataforma:

```
$ ionic platform add android
... 
$ ionic build android
...
```

Ten en cuenta que para hacer `build` de Android debes haber instalado y configurado el [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/index.html)

Para mayor información puedes visitar:

- [Guía de Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/)